# I am trying to extract a string out of a text file and because I am new to regular expressions therefore I am stuck

Tags: python, regex

I was searching a string through a `.txt` file. File consists of text:

```
Script dchsdpa uplink(Pxi_load_vector("i_and_v.aiq")
                      sim_recharge_bx('d_and_v.aiq')
```

The string I want to extract is:

```
i_and_v.aiq
d_and_v.aiq
```

Means only string inside quotes.

I have written the following code:

```
for line in input_file:
    match=re.findall(r"\S*.aiq\S*",line)
```

I know that `\S` will match any non-whitespace but I am not able to figure 
out how to get rid of extra text as I only need the string which I specified above.

It gives me output:

```
Pxi_load_vector("i_and_v.aiq")
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the whole file and then apply  `re.findall` function on that.

```
with open('file') as f:
    print re.findall(r"""(?<=')[^']*\.aiq(?=')|(?<=")[^"]*\.aiq(?=")""", f.read())
```

**Example:**

```
>>> s = '''Script dchsdpa uplink(Pxi_load_vector("i_and_v.aiq")
                      sim_recharge_bx('d_and_v.aiq')'''
>>> re.findall(r"""(?<=')[^']*\.aiq(?=')|(?<=")[^"]*\.aiq(?=")""", s)
['i_and_v.aiq', 'd_and_v.aiq']
```

**OR**

```
>>> [j for i in re.findall(r"""'([^']*\.aiq)'|"([^"]*\.aiq)\"""", s) for j in i if j]
['i_and_v.aiq', 'd_and_v.aiq']
```

**OR**

```
>>> [j for i in re.findall(r"""(['"])((?:(?!\1).)*\.aiq)\1""", s) for j in i if j not in ["'", '"']]
['i_and_v.aiq', 'd_and_v.aiq']
```

Comment: Could you not use a group in the lookbehind and then a backreference in the lookahead - it would shorten the pattern considerably. Does Python support backreferences?

Comment: @BoristheSpider no, re.findall function will print also the contents present inside the capturing group.

Comment: Interesting - wouldn't you be better of exploding the tuple rather than flatmapping it? Don't really know what the performance implications are of either solution - I suppose it doesn't really matter in this instance in any case.

Answer (score 0):

```
match=re.findall(r"""[^"']*\.aiq[^"']*""",line)
```

Use `negation based` matching with `[^"']*`

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/100#python

Comment: This doesn't enforce the _Means only string inside quotes_ requirement.